# How to give alert message without using javascript

Tags: asp.net

Hai to all,
                  How can i give alert message with ok and cancel button  within dataset function.if ok procced further else return  in asp.net .......pls help

Comment: are you trying to not use javascript at all, or just not use the alert box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use basic html to create a page that only has a small form in the centre of the page.
This would eliminate javascript.

Comment: That's not an alert, that's just a page.

Comment: It can look like an alert if its designed to look like one. If you mean a "Javascript alert box", indeed its isnt and that's what this question is all about. Its funny seeing a "-1" and an accepted answer :-)

Comment: @David Pfeffer: a practical solution is a better answer than the pedantic technically-correct answer of, "it's impossible".

Answer (score 4):

You can't show a client-sided message-box without using client-sided script.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. Both a standard browser alert window and a lightboxed one require JavaScript to display.

If you don't want to handcode the JavaScript, you can use the ASP.NET Ajaxtoolkit (http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) which contains a ModelPopup control that handles it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Add an "onclick" attribute to the object.
Page_load(){
 object.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:confirm('Are you sure')");
}

something like that.